# How do I use parameters key value when upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
var upsertDocument = function (db, table,kv,data) { 
db.collection(table).update(
{ kv },
{ $set: data },
{ upsert: true }
)
}
```

Can I have a code like this? pass kv(key,value) into a function as the parameter
Thanks.

```
upsertDocument(db,"MaxBlockSync",{idx:0},{blockNumber: 66});
```

my input is like this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? what are in the parameters? Which driver are you using? You need to show your inputs and explain.

Comment: upsertDocument(db,"MaxBlockSync",{idx:0},{blockNumber: 66});

my input is like this.
Thanks!

Comment: Please [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44819767/edit) with additional details. You also tagged this with nodejs, but you do not indicate if you are using the base driver, or mongoose, or mongskin or other variant. Or if in fact you are just using the mongo shell. We don't know. Try and string more than three words together and explain what you need to do and the result you expect. In the question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is correct. You can consider using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) so it will look like:

```
`var upsertDocument = function (table, kv, data) {
    table.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: kv._id},
        {
            $set: {
                name: data.name
            }
        },
        {upsert: true}
    )
}`
```